# How to run a gif on a window while waiting for a response from a server

Tags: c#

I wrote a client on c#, and I want to run a gif on a loading form I made while waiting for a response from my server.
Whenever I wait for a response from my server, the window just freezes until the message is received.
I was wondering if there is a way to run my window (and the gif) while also waiting for a response.

Comment: you need to run the server load on a separate thread

Comment: @pm100 could you show an example of that? I have never used threads in c#

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide implementation details, I can give you a crude example

```
public async Task LoadSomething()
{
    // Schedule the task on the thread pool and immediately return control.
    Task<MyResponse> serverCallTask = RunServerCallAsync();
    // Show the gif.
    RunGif();
    // Now we can await the result.
    await serverCallTask;
}
```

If you are not running your app on .NET core, you need to use
`await serverCallTask.ConfigureAwait(false);`
to avoid deadlock.

Asynchronous programming documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/
Further explanation and avoiding deadlock:
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html